# What is the Rust's equivalence of functional interface and method reference in Java

Tags: java, lambda, rust

In `Java`, we could take lambda expression or method reference as the interface parameter which only has one method. And this feature can simplify code greatly. For example,

```java
@FunctionalInterface
interface A {
    void execute();
}
class B {
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("foo in B");
    }
    public void bar() {
        System.out.println("bar in B");
    }
}
B b = new B();
```

Then for any method accepting `A a` as the parameter, we could pass `b::foo` or `b::bar` to it.

My question is: What is the Rust's equivalence of functional interface and method reference? It seems that Rust's trait does not provide such feature.

Comment: Are the [`Fn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Fn.html), [`FnMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnMut.html) and [`FnOnce`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnOnce.html) traits and their relation to [function pointers](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.fn.html) what you're looking for?

Comment: In Rust, we have traits that directly represent the notion of functions. There's no need to take a `Runnable` or some other wrapper type; you just take a function directly.

Answer (score 4):

You would typically implement it like so:

```rust
trait A {
    fn execute(&self) -> ();
}

impl<T> A for T where T: Fn() -> () {
    fn execute(&self) {
        self()
    }
}
```

The `impl` block will implement the trait for anything that is `Fn() -> ()`, which will match a normal function or lambda.

```rust
fn foo() {
    println!("foo")
}

fn use_a<T>(a: T) where T: A {
    a.execute()
}

fn main() {
    use_a(foo);
    use_a(|| println!("bar"));
}
```

If you want to use it as a function of `B`, you'd probably provide it as a lambda.

```rust
struct B {}

impl B {
    fn foo(&self) {
        println!("foo in B")
    }
    
    fn bar(&self) {
        println!("bar in B")
    }
}

fn use_a<T>(a: T) where T: A {
    a.execute()
}

fn main() {
    let b = B {};
    
    use_a(|| b.foo());
    use_a(|| b.bar());
}
```

You can test it on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b3063e193819f21e608d11b4adf4e9b1).